# How to show images in grids like iphone photo gallery does on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm working on an iphone app and want to have a page showing multiple images in multiple grids (each grid has a image that will response when a user tabs on it), like the default iphone photo gallery app would show image thumbnails.

The first thing came to my mind was tableview with customize cells. Each cell would display some buttons and each button represents an image and set the cell as non-selectable. So the user can tab the buttons (the images) but not the cell itself. But is this the best way? Is this how the built-in photo app does it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several open source grid views.

[AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Also previously answered here:

[Previous Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866766/how-to-create-a-gallery-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wait for iOS 6 (hint, hint).

Login to developer.apple.com and look at the [WWDC 2012 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) (i.e. What's New In Cocoa Touch).