# how to make gallery view

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Create A Gallery on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866766/how-to-create-a-gallery-on-ios)

How to make gallery view like in the image for in my application, Can any one give me some refrence?

[image]

Comment: look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866766/how-to-create-a-gallery-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

This code from get Image path from our gallery

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent intent)
  {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, intent);

  if (requestCode == 1)
  {
      if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK)
      {             

            Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: i was looking for gallery look , not accessing for gallery?

Comment: *What is the purpose of posting two answers in a single question?*